# renderLeaflet: legend values are not updated

Tags: r, shiny, legend, r-leaflet

I have the following R codes within the shiny framework. Everything looks good, but the legend ([Plese see this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4L8s.png)). 
I want the legend to be updated on the basis of the users' selection of age group (60+, 65+, 85+), sex, or year. But it is not the case. That is, the legend's values remain unchanged, no matter what is selected from the left menu ([Please see this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hg7JZ.png)). This makes the map useless if the 85+ is selected. Following is my entire codes.
I appreciate your help.
Nader

```
load("/Users/nadermehri/Desktop/map codes/nhmap.RData")

library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

ui <- fluidPage(
tabPanel(
  "Interactive Maps",

  tags$h5 (
  )),
  br(),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(
        inputId = "Age_Group_map",
        label = "Select the Age Group:",
        selected = "60+",
        selectize = F,
        multiple = F,
        choices = sort(unique(nhmap$Age_Group))
      ),


      radioButtons(
        inputId = "sex_map",
        label = strong("Select Sex:"),
        selected = "Both Sexes",
        choices = sort(unique(nhmap$Sex))
      ),

      sliderInput(
        inputId = "Year_map",
        label = "Year",
        min = 2010,
        max = 2050,
        value = 2010,
        step = 10,
        sep = "",
        pre = "",
        animate = animationOptions(
          interval = 1000,
          loop = F,
          playButton = tags$button("Play", style =
                                     "background-color: #B61E2E ; color:white; margin-top: 10px; border:solid"),
          pauseButton = tags$button("Pause", style =
                                      "background-color: #B61E2E !important; color:white; margin-top: 10px; border:solid")
        ),
        round = T,
        width = "150%",
        ticks = T
      )),

mainPanel("Interactive", leafletOutput("int_map", height=500))))

server <- function(input, output) {


    mapdata_ <- reactive ({

      nhmap$Per <- round(nhmap$Per, 1) 

      out_map <- nhmap %>%
        filter (
          Age_Group %in% input$Age_Group_map,
          Sex %in% input$sex_map,
          Year %in% input$Year_map)


      return(out_map)
    })


    output$int_map <- renderLeaflet ({


      leaflet (mapdata_(),

               pal8 <- c("#FFFFE5", "#D9F0A3", "#78C679", "#006837") ,
               pal <- colorBin(palette = pal8, domain = NULL, bins=quantile(nhmap$Per), na.color = "#808080",  alpha = FALSE, reverse = F)) %>%



        addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron") %>% 
        clearControls() %>%
        clearShapes()%>%
        addPolygons(fillColor = ~pal(Per),
                    stroke=T,
                    weight=1,
                    smoothFactor=0.2,
                    fillOpacity = 1,
                    color="black",
                    popup=~paste(NAME,"<br>",input$sex_map,
                                 input$Age_Group_map,"=",Per,"%"),
                    highlightOptions = highlightOptions(color = "red",
                                                        weight = T,
                                                        bringToFront = T),

                    label=~NAME) %>%


        addTiles() %>%

        setView(-82.706838, 40.358615, zoom=7) %>%

        addLegend(position = "bottomright",
                  values = ~Per,
                  pal = pal,
                  title = (paste("%",input$Age_Group_map, input$sex_map, "in", input$Year_map)) ,
                  labFormat = labelFormat(
                  ))

    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Can you share your data too (with `dput(nhmpa)`)and extent your code to a fully reproducible example? You also dont want to create `pal8` and `pal` inside the leaflet call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define the bins in `colorBin`, at which you want to cut the data in the different color sections. Something like:

```
pal <- colorBin(palette = pal8, domain = NULL, bins=quantile(mapdata_()$Per),
                na.color = "#808080",  alpha = FALSE, reverse = F)
```

And you also have to remove `bins= 4` from the `addLegend` call, as it will get the information from the color palette.

---

I created some random data for `nhmap` and it is working for me with this code:

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(sf)
library(sp)

## Random Data #############
data(meuse, package = "sp")
nhmap <- st_as_sf(meuse, coords = c("x", "y"))
st_crs(nhmap) <- "+init=epsg:28992"
nhmap <- st_buffer(nhmap, 100)

n = length(nhmap$cadmium)
nhmap$Age_Group <- sample(c(15,19,25), size = n, T)
nhmap$Sex <- sample(c("m","f"), size = n, T)
nhmap$Per <- runif(n, 1, 150)
nhmap$NAME <- sample(c("a","b","c"), size = n, T)
nhmap$Age_Group <- sample(c(15,19,25), size = n, T)
nhmap$Year <- sample(c(2010,2020,2030, 2040, 2050), size = n, T)
nhmap <- st_transform(nhmap, 4326)


## UI ###########
ui <- {fluidPage(
  tabPanel(
    "Interactive Maps",
    tags$h5 ()),
  br(),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(
        inputId = "Age_Group_map",
        label = "Select the Age Group:",
        # selected = "60+",
        selectize = F,
        multiple = F,
        choices = sort(unique(nhmap$Age_Group))
      ),


      radioButtons(
        inputId = "sex_map",
        label = strong("Select Sex:"),
        # selected = "Both Sexes",
        choices = sort(unique(nhmap$Sex))
      ),

      sliderInput(
        inputId = "Year_map",
        label = "Year",
        min = 2010,
        max = 2050,
        value = 2010,
        step = 10,
        sep = "",
        pre = "",
        animate = animationOptions(
          interval = 1000,
          loop = F,
          playButton = tags$button("Play", style =
                                     "background-color: #B61E2E ; color:white; margin-top: 10px; border:solid"),
          pauseButton = tags$button("Pause", style =
                                      "background-color: #B61E2E !important; color:white; margin-top: 10px; border:solid")
        ),
        round = T,
        width = "150%",
        ticks = T
      )),

    mainPanel("Interactive", leafletOutput("int_map", height=500)))
)}

## SERVER ###########
server <- function(input, output) {

  mapdata_ <- reactive ({
    nhmap$Per <- round(nhmap$Per, 1)
    # nhmap
    nhmap %>%
      filter (
        Age_Group %in% input$Age_Group_map,
        Sex %in% input$sex_map,
        Year %in% input$Year_map)
  })

  output$int_map <- renderLeaflet ({
    req(mapdata_())
    pal8 <- c("#FFFFE5", "#D9F0A3", "#78C679", "#006837")
    # pal <- colorBin(palette = pal8, domain = NULL, bins=quantile(mapdata_()$Per), 
    pal <- colorBin(palette = pal8, domain = NULL, bins=quantile(nhmap$Per), 
                    na.color = "#808080",  alpha = FALSE, reverse = F)


    leaflet(data = mapdata_()) %>%
      # leaflet(data = nhmap) %>% 
      clearControls() %>%
      clearShapes()%>%
      addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron") %>% 
      addTiles() %>%
      addPolygons(fillColor = ~pal(Per),
                  stroke=T,
                  weight=1,
                  smoothFactor=0.2,
                  fillOpacity = 1,
                  color="black",
                  label=~NAME,
                  popup=~paste(NAME,"<br>",input$sex_map,
                               input$Age_Group_map,"=",Per,"%"),
                  highlightOptions = highlightOptions(color = "red",
                                                      weight = T,
                                                      bringToFront = T)) %>%

      # setView(-82.706838, 40.358615, zoom=7) %>%

      addLegend(position = "bottomright",
                values = ~Per,
                title = (paste("%",input$Age_Group_map, input$sex_map, "in", input$Year_map)),
                pal = pal
      )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I ran "dput(nhmap, file="nhmap") in my R studio Console. I guess you may have access to data now. I also put the entire shiny code in the above gray box. It is completely reproducible if you have access to data. I appreciate your further help.

Comment: You have to include the output of `dput(nhmap)` in your question, than we can import your data aswell. But anyway, does my answer solve your problem?

Comment: Yes, it did. However, a new issue came up which I explained in the body (above gray box). I assume you may have access to my data by running dget("nhmap"). I also posted the entire code in the body.

Comment: You didnt include the output of `dput(nhmap)`, so I cannot import your data.

Comment: Please try this: dget("nhmap.txt")

Comment: Your data is local on your computer! You have to include the console output of `dput(nhmap)` in your question. I dont have any file called `nhmap.txt`...

Comment: Did you try out the server function that I posted? You could make a small subset of the data and post this then, if my answer is not working.

Comment: Yes, I did try out the server function that you posted; it did not work. Nothing changed!.

Comment: I included a whole shiny app, which is working with some random data.

Comment: Great! Thanks. I could make the same map using my data too. However, the problem is that I want the legend values to be updated when different age groups are selected. Different age groups have different ranges.

Comment: I think that I need to make "pal" reactive. I need something like the following.                                                                                                                                 
 pal8 <- c("#FFFFE5", "#D9F0A3", "#78C679", "#006837")     
 pal <- colorQuantile(palette = pal8, domain =NULL, bins=quantile(out_map$Per), na.color = "#808080",  alpha = FALSE, reverse = F). However, "out_map" is a function, not a dataset and therefore I get the error of "unused argument (bins = quantile(out_map()$Per))".

Comment: No you dont need to make the pal reactive. It would be reactive, but you have to change the colorBin function from `bins=quantile(nhmap$Per)` to `bins=quantile(mapdata_()$Per)`. If you would share a sample of your data I could show you much easier.

Comment: You are right. I found your answer out. Please see the second answer which I posted in response to my question. Thanks.

Comment: I edited my answer aswell, and the inputs will change the shown polygons and colors. If you like my answer you can check and upvote it. This will give me some credit and you'll gain some points too ;)

Comment: Sure! could you clarify how can I check and upvote it? I am very new in Stackoverflow. Also, I was wondering if there is a way to impose my categories of interest into the map as well as legend's labels. In my question, the quantile option categorizes the Per unevenly which does not look reasonable. I would like to impose my own categories. I know that it would be so helpful to attach my data, but due to a variable called "geometry", my data is extremely lengthy even if a small subset of the data is selected.

Comment: Left of the answer is the number 0 and some triangles on top/below. They are for voting up or down. Below the bottom triangle is a checkmark, which accepts an answer that solved the problem. About your other question with own categories, you could either do some research or post in as another question. Maybe you could read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer. As I mentioned in my the last comment, the pal needs to be reactive:

```
mapdata_ <- reactive ({



 nhmap$Per <- round(nhmap$Per, 1) 

 out_map <- nhmap %>%
   filter (
     Age_Group %in% input$Age_Group_map,
      Sex %in% input$sex_map,
     Year %in% input$Year_map)

 return(out_map)
 list(Per)



})

  mapdata_1 <- reactive ({



nhmap$Per <- round(nhmap$Per, 1) 

out_map_1 <- nhmap %>%
  filter (
    Age_Group %in% input$Age_Group_map
    )

return(out_map_1)
list(Per)



})



  output$int_map <- renderLeaflet ({

pal8 <- c("#FFFFE5", "#D9F0A3", "#78C679", "#006837") 
pal <- colorBin(palette = pal8, domain =NULL, bins=quantile(mapdata_1()$Per), na.color = "#808080",  alpha = FALSE, reverse = F)

 leaflet (mapdata_()) %>% 
                    addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron") %>% 
                 clearControls() %>%
                 clearShapes()%>%
                    addPolygons(fillColor = ~pal(Per),
                               stroke=T,
                               weight=1,
                               smoothFactor=0.2,
                               fillOpacity = 1,
                               color="black",
                               popup=~paste(NAME,"<br>",input$sex_map,
                                            input$Age_Group_map,"=",Per,"%"),
                                highlightOptions = highlightOptions(color = "red",
                                                                    weight = T,
                                                                    bringToFront = T),

                               label=~NAME) %>%


                               addTiles() %>%

  setView(-82.706838, 40.358615, zoom=7) %>%

                    addLegend(position = "bottomright",
                     values = ~Per,
                     pal = pal,
                     title = (paste("%",input$Age_Group_map, input$sex_map, "in", input$Year_map)) ,
                   labFormat = labelFormat(
                  ))

    })
```